# PHP Missing User Input from form when sent to email

Tags: php, html, webforms, submit

I created a form using phpform.org And with some help from Mohamed Athif have now got a partially working mail.php , I am now receiving emails but I cant get the user input into the email. I Understand That I have to add the elements in for each field in the .php file. If someone can give some guidance to getting these few element working withing the email so I can then apply them to the all the other elements myself here is the html code.

For Element 1,8,6 in the email I want it to be as follows or similar to this

```
    What alias do you want to use - (User Input)
    Is this about - (whatever the user clicked either good Job or bad Job)
    What is the name of the workplace.. (user Input)
```

Currently in the email Im getting this

```
From: alias
 Message: Is this about a , Where is this Business Located? element6,
```

so you can see that the user input is missing.

```
    <form method="post" action="mail.php">
                <div class="form_description">
        <h2>GoodJob - BadJob</h2>
        <p>some text here</p>
    </div>                      
        <ul >

                <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="element_1">What is the Alias you want to use </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>You don't have to use your real name - Just remember your Alias for Comments</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_8" >
    <label class="description" for="element_8">Is this about a ...... </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_8_1" name="element_8" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_8_1">Bad job</label>
<input id="element_8_2" name="element_8" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_8_2">Good Job</label>

    </span> 
    </li>       <li id="li_6" >
    <label class="description" for="element_6">What is the name of the workplace you want to tell us about? </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_6"><small>Type in the Name of the Business</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_16" >
    <label class="description" for="element_16">Where is this Business Located? </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_16" name="element_16" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_16"><small>Type in the town, or you can find the business on google maps and click on share and copy the link and paste it here.</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_7" >
    <label class="description" for="element_7">If you want to mention the bosses name, Put it here. </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_7"><small>Type in the Name of the Boss</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_15" >
    <label class="description" for="element_15">If you know the personal page you can copy and paste it in here </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_15" name="element_15" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_15"><small>Go to the top address bar of the boss/owner  you want to tag for this post. Select all the text and paste it in the box.</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_9" >
    <label class="description" for="element_9">How many hours a week do you work? </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_9_1" name="element_9" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
```

1 to 10

10 to 20

20 to 30

30 to 40

40 to 50

50 hours Plus

```
    </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_9"><small>Keep it REAL. </small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_18" >
    <label class="description" for="element_18">Exactly how many hours do you work? </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_18" name="element_18" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_11" >
    <label class="description" for="element_11">Does your Job Pay Extra Hours? </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_11_1" name="element_11" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
```

Yes

No

```
    </span> 
    </li>       <li id="li_10" >
    <label class="description" for="element_10">What type of contract do you have? </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_10_1" name="element_10" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
```

Part Time

Full Time

Hourly per week

Dont know

```
    </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_10"><small>DON'T GUESS..This is crucial. Every worker MUST have a copy of their contract. If you don't have one ask your boss or go to the Employment office with ALL your credentials and they will tell you there what contract you have.</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_12" >
    <label class="description" for="element_12">Did you get Holiday pay? </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_12_1" name="element_12" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
```

Yes

No

```
    </span> 
    </li>       <li id="li_17" >
    <label class="description" for="element_17">How much holiday pay did you get? </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_17" name="element_17" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_17"><small>A NUMBER ONLY no symbols or text</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_13" >
    <label class="description" for="element_13">Did you know That </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_13_1" name="element_13" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
```

Yes

No

```
    </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_13"><small>Its true, In Spain ins a 14 month pay scheme, where you get a double pay in summer and another Christmas. Most employers will actually incorporate these two payments within your monthly wage</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_14" >
    <label class="description" for="element_14">Got a story to tell about this Job? Bad or good - let it rip here!</label>
    <div>
        <textarea id="element_14" name="element_14" class="element textarea large"></textarea> 
    </div> 
    </li>

                <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1136056" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

and the PHP is as follows

```
<?php 
$element1 = $_POST['element_1'];
$element8 = $_POST['element_8'];
$element6 = $_POST['element_6'];

$formcontent="From: $element1 \n Message: Is this about a $element81, Where is this Business Located? element6, blah blah blah";
$recipient = "me@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $element1 \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Mail sent successfully!')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code, in that case only the HTML form elements and the PHP part. Explain what you expect as a result and describe the errors.

Comment: Changed the code and given what I'd hoped to get ant what I am Actually getting upon receiving the email.

Comment: I see you got the answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code, you
1) called an non-existing variable $element81
2) there is a $ sign missing before element6
that's why you didn't get the required content.

The code below will give you the following content in your email (as per your request)

What alias do you want to use - (User Input)
Is this about - (whatever the user clicked either good Job or bad Job)
What is the name of the workplace.. (user Input)

replace

```
$formcontent="From: $element1 \n Message: Is this about a $element81, Where is this Business Located? element6, blah blah blah";
```

with

```
$formcontent="What alias do you want to use - $element1\n";
$formcontent.="Is this about -  $element8\n";
$formcontent.="Where is this Business Located? - $element6\n";
```

Comment: Thats great I can now apply that to the other fields, Only that on the $element 8 the value is set to value="1" or value= "2" and on the mail I get the value figure. I have changed it to value="bad" and value="good" it seems to work. is that change going to create any problems

Comment: That's fine, what inside the quotation mark of value=" " is what get passed to your php script. If you do change the name attribute (i.e. element8), you would need to do that on both the HTML and the PHP script.

Comment: @user6439245 36 rep on your first day... Do you know how long it took me to get 36 rep when I joined up? *Of course, back then I didn't know my .asp from a hole in the ground...* Well done, keep it up. +1.

Comment: @gibberish Thanks a lot for the encouragement. Actually I had a rough start here today, as the first question I posted has been put on hold for being off topic and my first attempt at answering a question was reviewed for quality check. I am trying my best to get my rep up to 50 asap so I can post comment to clarify requirement before submitting my answer, so thanks again for the encouragement. Much appreciated.

Comment: Most important tip - don't let the downvoters get to you. There's a sizeable number of folks who, having received downvote power, feel obligated to use it. Frequently, and with little cause. *Usually, the downvotes are for questions where OP does not show what was already tried, but too many times there is just no good reason.* Ignore the powertrippers and get all you can from this site -- it's an amazing resource.